# Why C# convert date time format when query from db

Tags: c#, mysql

When I get data from Mysql table the datetime column `2017-09-19 16:14:47` will automatically convert into its own format like `9/19/2017 3:45:50 PM`. It happens when I'm getting data into `DataTable` and convert into string as follows:

```
DataTable update;
localdb.MysqlQuery(queryUpdate);
update = localdb.QueryEx();

if (update.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    onlinedb = new DataAccessOnline();

    foreach (DataRow row in update.Rows)
    {
        row["added"].ToString(); //9/19/2017 3:45:50 PM
```

but I need get this value as it is in TABLE column `2017-09-19 16:14:47` how can I do that ?

Comment: using this code: Convert.ToDateTime(row["added"].ToString());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to convert the data you get from the DB into a DateTime object using the [Convert.ToDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx) method.
Then you can specify the format you want on the [DateTime.toString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method.

It would look something like this:

```
DateTime added = Convert.ToDateTime(row["added"].ToString());
string formatted = added.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can format it in your server side query as string.

mySql is giving data to C# as datetime type. C# has slightly different format of interpreting and presenting datetime type value to you. Ultimately, data will work like a datetime field anyways.

If you bring it like a formatted string, you would need to convert it to datetime in C# to make it function like a datetime. On the other hand, if you want it to be converted in C# for presentation purposes, do it in C#, not while bringing data because then it would be a string, not datetime.

[You can see more .ToString() conversion details here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx)

Default format you need is "u", but you can provide your own format string like this one.

```
string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```